# I have a text file that contains information I need to extract and export to a spreadsheet

Tags: batch-file, powershell-2.0

My NetBackup schedule text file has data fields which needs to be extracted and grouped.

Here is an example that has two policies:

```
POLICIES

Policy Name:    Windows_Server_1

Policy Type:    MS-Windows-NT
Active:         no
Effective Date:    06/24/2014 01:00:00
Backup network drives:    no
Collect TIR info:    no
Mult. Data Streams:    no
Client Enctypt:    no
Checkpoint:    no
Policy Priority:    0
Max Jobs/Policy:     Unlimited
Disastery Recovery:    0
Collect BMR info:    no
Residence:    BackupSrv01-hcart2
Volume Pool:    NetBackup
Server group:    *Any*
Keyword:    (none specified)
Residence is Lifecycle Policy:    no

Granular Restore Info:    no
HW/OS/Client: PC    Windows2008    WinServer01

Include:    All_Local_Drives

Schedule:     Full
Type:    Full Backup
Frequency:    every 7 days
Maximum MPX:    1
Synthetic:        0
PFI Recovery:     0
Retention Level:    8
Number Copies:    0
Fail on error:    0
Residence:    (specific storage unit not required)
Volume Pool:    (same as policy volume pool)
Server Group:    (Same as specified for policy)
Residence is Storage Lifecycle Policy:    0


Policy Name:    Unix_Server_10

Policy Type:    Unix
Active:         no
Effective Date:    06/24/2014 01:00:00
Backup network drives:    no
Collect TIR info:    no
Mult. Data Streams:    no
Client Enctypt:    no
Checkpoint:    no
Policy Priority:    0
Max Jobs/Policy:     Unlimited
Disastery Recovery:    0
Collect BMR info:    no
Residence:    BackupSrv01-hcart2
Volume Pool:    NetBackup
Server group:    *Any*
Keyword:    (none specified)
Residence is Lifecycle Policy:    no

Granular Restore Info:    no
HW/OS/Client: Unix    Unix    Unix_Server_10 

Include:    All_Local_Drives

Schedule:     Full
Type:    Full Backup
Frequency:    every 7 days
Maximum MPX:    1
Synthetic:        0
PFI Recovery:     0
Retention Level:    8
Number Copies:    0
Fail on error:    0
Residence:    (specific storage unit not required)
Volume Pool:    (same as policy volume pool)
Server Group:    (Same as specified for policy)
Residence is Storage Lifecycle Policy:    0
```

---

The output I want for a spreadsheet for each policy include the following fields:

- Policy Name
- Policy Type
- HW
- OS
- Client
- Include
- Schedule

There are perhaps 50-60 policies on a text file. 
I am working on a powershell - but getting no where. :(

The simpler the better...

Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
::
:: General-purpose CSV generator
::
CALL :zap$#
:: Column-names in output order
SET /a outcolumns=0
FOR %%a IN ("Policy Name" "Policy Type" Keyword
            HW OS Client Include Schedule) DO CALL :set# %%a
:: Where does a new data item begin?
SET "newdataitem=Policy Name"
:: Read-and-generate
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN (q27672783.txt) DO (
 IF "%%a"=="%newdataitem%" CALL :showline
 SET "#0=%%a"
 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%c IN ("%%b") DO SET "newdata=%%c"&CALL :set$ 
)
IF DEFINED $0 CALL :showline
)>"newfile.txt"
GOTO :EOF

:: Increment outcolumn count & record name & record header & set 'header loaded'
:set#
SET /a outcolumns+=1
SET #%outcolumns%=%~1
SET $%outcolumns%=%~1
SET $0=Y
GOTO :eof

:: Store newdata in column #0
:set$
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%d IN ('set #') DO IF "%%e"=="%#0%" SET selected=%%d
SET "$%selected:~1%=%newdata%"
SET $0=Y
GOTO :eof

:showline
SET "outline="
FOR /L %%g IN (1,1,%outcolumns%) DO (CALL SET "outline=%%outline%%,"%%$%%g%%"")
ECHO %outline:~1%
)
CALL :zap$
GOTO :eof

:: remove variables starting $ or #
:zap$#
For %%b IN ($ #) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
GOTO :eof

:: remove variables starting $
:ZAP$
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
GOTO :eof
```

Here's a primitive CSV generator for such files. Each filed produced would be quoted. There is no "HW" or "OS" or "Client" data item in the data you provided - They mean something to you, not me - you must be explicit. I added the "keyword" column just to demonstrate that `(parenthesised word sequences)` are correctly processed, but as I said, 'tis primitive and would likely not deal cleanly with many common text forms, nor have I ventured to quote only fileds containing column-separators (commas in this case)

I used a file named `q27672783.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt